# custom jenkins declarative pipeline dsl with named arguments

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I've been trying for a while now to start working towards moving our free style projects over to pipeline. To do so I feel like it would be best to build up a shared library since most of our builds are the same. I read through this [blog post from Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/10/02/pipeline-templates-with-shared-libraries/). I came up with the following

```groovy
// vars/buildGitWebProject.groovy
def call(body) {
    def args= [:]
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body.delegate = args
    body()

    pipeline {
        agent {
            node {
                label 'master'
                customWorkspace "c:\\jenkins_repos\\${args.repositoryName}\\${args.branchName}"
            }
        }
        environment {
            REPOSITORY_NAME = "${args.repositoryName}"
            BRANCH_NAME = "${args.branchName}"
            SOLUTION_NAME = "${args.solutionName}"
        }
        options {
            buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '3'))
            skipStagesAfterUnstable()
            timestamps()
        }
        stages {
            stage("checkout") {
                steps {
                    script{
                        assert REPOSITORY_NAME != null : "repositoryName is null. Please include it in configuration."
                        assert BRANCH_NAME != null : "branchName is null. Please include it in configuration."
                        assert SOLUTION_NAME != null : "solutionName is null. Please include it in configuration."
                    }
                    echo "building with ${REPOSITORY_NAME}"
                    echo "building with ${BRANCH_NAME}"
                    echo "building with ${SOLUTION_NAME}"
                    checkoutFromGitWeb(args)
                }
            }
            stage('build and test') {
                steps {
                    executeRake(
                        "set_assembly_to_current_version",
                        "build_solution[$args.solutionName, Release, Any CPU]",
                        "copy_to_deployment_folder",
                        "execute_dev_dropkick"
                    )
                }
            }
        }
        post {
            always {
                sendEmail(args)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

in my pipeline project I configured the Pipeline to use Pipeline script and the script is as follows:

```groovy
buildGitWebProject {
    repositoryName:'my-git-repo'
    branchName: 'qa'
    solutionName: 'my_csharp_solution.sln'
    emailTo='testuser@domain.com'
}
```

I've tried with and without the environment block but the result ends up being the same that the value is 'null' for each of those arguments. Oddly enough the script portion of the code doesn't make the build fail either... so not sure what's wrong with that. Also the echo parts show null as well. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I should point out that I did try using `call(Map args)` as well but something was wrong with my syntax either in the script or the global dsl. (sorry if naming is wrong)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `Closure` body is not behaving the way you expect/believe it should.

At the beginning of your method you have:

```groovy
def call(body) {
  def args= [:]
  body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
  body.delegate = args
  body()
```

Your call body is:

```groovy
buildGitWebProject {
    repositoryName:'my-git-repo'
    branchName: 'qa'
    solutionName: 'my_csharp_solution.sln'
    emailTo='testuser@domain.com'
}
```

Let's take a stab at debugging this.

If you add a `println(args)` after the `body()` in your `call(body)` method you will see something like this:

> [emailTo:testuser@domain.com]

But, only one of the values got set. What is going on?

There are a few things to understand here:

1. What does setting a `delegate` of a `Closure` do?
2. Why does `repositoryName:'my-git-repo'` not do anything?
3. Why does `emailTo='testuser@domain.com'` set the property in the map?

> What does setting a `delegate` of a `Closure` do?

This one is mostly straightforward, but I think it helps to understand. [`Closure`](http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html) is powerful and is the Swiss Army knife of Groovy. The `delegate` essentially sets what the `this` is in the body of the `Closure`. You are also using the `resolveStrategy` of `Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST`, so methods and properties from the delegate are checked first, and then from the enclosing scope (owner) - see the [Javadoc](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Closure.html#DELEGATE_FIRST) for an in-depth explanation. If you call methods like `size()`, `put(...)`, `entrySet()`, etc., they are all first called on the `delegate`. The same is true for property access.

> Why does `repositoryName:'my-git-repo'` not do anything?

This may appear to be a [Groovy map literal](http://groovy-lang.org/groovy-dev-kit.html#_map_literals), but it is not. These are actually [labeled statements](http://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#_labeled_statements). If you surround it instead with square brackets like `[repositoryName:'my-git-repo']` then that would be a map literal. But, that is all you would be doing there - is creating a map literal. We want to make sure that these objects are consumed in the `Closure`

> Why does `emailTo='testuser@domain.com'` set the property in the map?

This is using the [map property notation](http://groovy-lang.org/groovy-dev-kit.html#_map_property_notation) feature of Groovy. As mentioned earlier, you have set the `delegate` of the `Closure` to `def args= [:]`, which is a `Map`. You also set the `resolveStrategy` of `Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST`. This makes your `emailTo='testuser@domain.com'` resolve to being called on `args`, which is why the `emailTo` key is set to the value. This is equivalent to calling `args.emailTo='testuser@domain.com'`.

So, how do you fix this?

If you want to keep your `Closure` syntax approach, you could change the body of your call to anything that essentially stores values in the delegated `args` map:

```groovy
buildGitWebProject {
  repositoryName = 'my-git-repo'
  branchName = 'qa'
  solutionName = 'my_csharp_solution.sln'
  emailTo = 'testuser@domain.com'
}

buildGitWebProject {
  put('repositoryName', 'my-git-repo')
  put('branchName', 'qa')
  put('solutionName', 'my_csharp_solution.sln')
  put('emailTo', 'testuser@domain.com')
}

buildGitWebProject {
  delegate.repositoryName = 'my-git-repo'
  delegate.branchName = 'qa'
  delegate.solutionName = 'my_csharp_solution.sln'
  delegate.emailTo = 'testuser@domain.com'
}

buildGitWebProject {
  // example of Map literal where the square brackets are not needed
  putAll(
      repositoryName:'my-git-repo',
      branchName: 'qa',
      solutionName: 'my_csharp_solution.sln',
      emailTo: 'testuser@domain.com'
  )
}
```

Another way would be to have your `call` take in the `Map` as an argument and remove your `Closure`.

```groovy
def call(Map args) {
    // no more args and delegates needed right now
}
```

```groovy
buildGitWebProject(
    repositoryName: 'my-git-repo',
    branchName: 'qa',
    solutionName: 'my_csharp_solution.sln',
    emailTo: 'testuser@domain.com'
)
```

There are also some other ways you could model your API, it will depend on the UX you want to provide.

---

Side note around declarative pipelines in shared library code:

It's worth keeping in mind the limitations of declarative pipelines in shared libraries. It looks like you are already doing it in `vars`, but I'm just adding it here for completeness. At the very end of the [documentation it is stated](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#defining-declarative-pipelines):

> Only entire `pipeline`s can be defined in shared libraries as of this time. This can only be done in `vars/*.groovy`, and only in a `call` method. Only one Declarative Pipeline can be executed in a single build, and if you attempt to execute a second one, your build will fail as a result.

Comment: lol.. good catch with the `=` and the `:` I missed changing that when going from a method call to a closure call (still reading your post)

Comment: i switched all of assignments to be `=` and now the build is working. I need to read your answer a few more times till I understand it fully though. As it stands you gave me the hint I needed to fix the issue so thank you

Comment: Glad that it helped - I tried to pack in some Groovy information in the answer so that it would make sense as to what was wrong. Groovy is already a tough language, and figuring out the special Jenkins parts of it can make it even more difficult.